# How to select time with React DatePicker

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, datepicker

I'm using [React Date Picker](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker) and I need also include time to the Date selection. I didn't find any example from documentation how to implement this. Does DatePicker provide any functionality for this out of box, or do I have to customize it myself?

Comment: Please post the answer

Answer (score 9):

just add `showTimeSelect`

```
 <DatePicker
    selected={this.state.startDate}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    showTimeSelect
    timeFormat="HH:mm"
    timeIntervals={15}
    dateFormat="LLL"
    />
```

check more examples @ [reactdatepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `react-date-picker` module for a date with a timestamp.
You can include the time by including timestamp in your `dateFormat` property.

E.g.: `dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"`

EDIT: 
Original links are not working anymore. Here's more information about `react-date-picker`. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-picker

Original links:

> http://zippyui.com/docs/react-date-picker/
>   https://github.com/zippyui/react-date-picker/