# React Datepicker. How to save time in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

Currently, I'm creating a mini-project in order to learn React. I'm using React Datepicker for my booking page. It's easy to save a chosen date in state:

```
state = {
            startDate: new Date(),
            time: null 
} 
handleChange = (date) => {
    this.setState( {startDate: date} )         
}
<DatePicker
        selected={this.state.startDate}
        locale="ru"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        minTime={setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 9)}
        maxTime={setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 22)}
        showTimeSelect
        timeIntervals={60}
        inline
/>
```

But I don't understand how to save time in the state as well. If a user doesn't choose the time, the current time will be saved but it's not what I want. I need to have **"time"** as a requirement and save it correctly in the state.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38179473/how-to-select-time-with-react-datepicker

Comment: https://reactdatepicker.com/

Comment: Thank you, but it was already included in my code.

Answer (score 1):

set your state as below

```
  state={
        startDate:new Date()
        }

        return (
        <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
      timeInputLabel="Time:"
      dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy h:mm aa"
      showTimeInput
    />
      );
```

Comment: Thank you but what I need is to have "time" and "date" separately in my state.

Comment: @xenia I edited my code please check. now, you will get time & date in onChange.

Comment: Thank you for your work! Anyway, I don't understand how i will get time & date separately in state, if it's only "startDate" there. What i need is "state = { day: "", time: "" }

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end I had to add my own time component and use it.